# Create objects based on date and time

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an Event model, and each event will have different shows.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Show(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
```

I have another Ticket model. Each ticket should be unique. Meaning each ticket will be unique and relate to a Show and a Seat.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('show', 'seat')
```

I need to create shows based on the start date and end date provide by the user. Suppose this is a JSON post:

```
{
    "event_id": 1,
    "start_date": "2018-02-16",
    "end_date": "2018-02-20",
    "time_list": ["11:00 AM", "8:00 PM"]
}
```

From the above JSON example, I need to create Show starting like this:

```
# Start with the start_date as the date, and for each time from the time_list
Show.objects.create(
    event = 1,
    date_time = datetime.strptime('2018-02-16 11:00 AM', "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
)
Show.objects.create(
    event = 1,
    date_time = datetime.strptime('2018-02-16 8:00 PM', "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
)
# Next date after the start_date, i.e., 16+1 = 17
Show.objects.create(
    event = 1,
    date_time = datetime.strptime('2018-02-17 8:00 PM', "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
)
.
.
.
# Create Show objects till the end_date and for each time from the time_list
Show.objects.create(
    event = 1,
    date_time = datetime.strptime('2018-02-20 8:00 PM', "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
)
```

Right now this is how I am creating Show objects:

```
def create_show_by_datetime(self, request):
    event_id = request.data['event_id']
    try:
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(
            {'error': 'event with id: %s does not exist.' % event_id},
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

    start_date = request.data['start_date']
    end_date = request.data['end_date']
    time_list = request.data['time_list']
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
    time_format = "%I:%M %p"
    try:
        datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
        datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format)
        for i in range(len(time_list)):
            time = datetime.strptime(time_list[i], time_format)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(
            {'error': 'Time was not in a supported format. %s' % e},
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

    delta_days = datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format).date() - datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format).date()
    delta_days = delta_days.days + 1
    dt = None
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            for i in range(delta_days):
                day = datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format) + timedelta(days=i)
                for i in range(len(time_list)):
                    hrs = datetime.strptime(time_list[i], time_format).hour
                    mins = datetime.strptime(time_list[i], time_format).minute
                    dt = day + timedelta(hours=hrs, minutes=mins)
                    show = Show.objects.create(
                        event=event,
                        date_time=dt
                    )
            return Response({"data": 'Post succesfull'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        return Response(
            {
                'error': "event with date and time already exsits. %s-%s-%s at %s:%s" % (
                    dt.day, dt.month, dt.year, dt.hour, dt.minute),
                'detail': str(e)
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

But I am hoping there's much more elegant way than how I am doing. I am using python 3, django 2 and django rest frameowork. How can I create **Show**s with the event, and date_time based on the `event_id`, `start_date`, `end_date` and the `time_list`?

Comment: how can u save the posting data??? There is not enough fields to map the data to DB

Comment: @Ananthu Using for loops maybe?

Comment: In your payload you are passing `start_date`,`end_date` and `time_list`. Can you explain why is that for?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 6):

My approach is a little bit different. You said in the question tag that you are using `django-rest-framework`.. So where are the serializers? :)

Lets create two serializers, one for user data validation (Because we don't trust the USER!) and one for multi data insert.

*I haven't checked the code! But you can use it was an example...*

```
class ShowEventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    event_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    end_date = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    time_list = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.TimeField()
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ('event_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'time_list')

class ShowSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date_time = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Show
        fields = ('event', 'date_time')
```

Now, with the serializers, we are going to validate the user data and then to create a json data object:

```
def create_show_by_datetime(self, request):

    show_event_serializer = ShowEventSerializer(data=request.data)
    if not show_event_serializer.is_valid():
        return Response({'error': show_event_serializer.errors},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    event_id = show_event_serializer.data['event_id']
    try:
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'error': 'event with id: %s does not exist.' % event_id},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    start_date = show_event_serializer.data['start_date']
    end_date = show_event_serializer.data['end_date']
    time_list = show_event_serializer.data['time_list']
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
    time_format = "%I:%M %p"

    try:
        datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
        datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format)
        for i in range(len(time_list)):
            time = datetime.strptime(time_list[i], time_format)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(
            {'error': 'Time was not in a supported format. %s' % e},
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

    delta_days = datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format).date() - datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format).date()
    delta_days = delta_days.days + 1
    dt = None
    show_data = []
    for i in range(delta_days):
        day = datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format) + timedelta(days=i)
        for i in range(len(time_list)):
            hrs = datetime.strptime(time_list[i], time_format).hour
            mins = datetime.strptime(time_list[i], time_format).minute
            dt = day + timedelta(hours=hrs, minutes=mins)
            show_data.append({
                "event": event,
                "date_time": dt
            })

    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            show_serializer = ShowSerializer(data=show_data, many=True)
            if show_serializer.is_valid():
                show_serializer.save()

            return Response({"data": 'Post succesfull'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        return Response(
            {
                'error': "event with date and time already exsits. %s-%s-%s at %s:%s" % (
                    dt.day, dt.month, dt.year, dt.hour, dt.minute),
                'detail': str(e)
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

So this code is basically the same as yours, with the difference of the way the objects are saved using the DRF. Look the `show_data` variable.

This solution is just a different way of looking at the question.

GOOD LUCK!

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

[http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield)

Answer (score 4):

Then your `Show` model should look like

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Show(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    board = ArrayField(
        models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True),
        size=10, # specify max array size
    )
```

so you'll have model `Show` with specified `DateFields` and array of `TimeFields`.

django docs: [Array Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield), [Time Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield), [Date Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

Comment: Acrtually, I have another Ticket model. Each ticket should be unique. Meaning each ticket will relate to a Show and a Seat. Therefore I think, it is better to have a separate Show instead. I have updated the question please have a look.

Answer (score 4):

There are some tools in the datetime library that can give you a more streamlined approach to generating your times. You can use `toordinal` to turn a date into an integer and `fromordinal` to turn an integer back into a date; this makes a nice way to create a range of dates. And you can use `combine` to merge a `date` object and a `time` object into a `datetime`. I'd create the following function:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def get_showtimes(post):
    start = datetime.strptime(post['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    end = datetime.strptime(post['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    times = [datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M %p').time() for t in post['time_list']]
    for ordinal in range(start.toordinal(), end.toordinal() + 1):
        date = date.fromordinal(date)
        for time in times:
            yield datetime.combine(date, time)
```

then, in your code, replace the second `try: except:` block and what follows it with:

```
try:
    showtimes = list(get_showtimes(post))
except ValueError as e:
    return Response(
        {'error': 'Time was not in a supported format. %s' % e},
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    )

try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        for showtime in showtimes:
            show = Show.objects.create(event=event, date_time=showtime)
except IntegrityError as e:
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

I am leaving the validation part and only focusing on generating `Show` objects from the given data:

```
data = request.data

date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
time_format = "%I:%M %p"
show_time_format = f"{date_format} {time_format}"

# get the total number of days by parsing start and end dates
start_date = datetime.strptime(data['start_date'], date_format)
end_date = datetime.strptime(data['end_date'], date_format)
total_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1

# Get the timings for the first day.
# We will use this to generate the timings for the rest of the days.
first_day_timings = [
    datetime.strptime(f"{data['start_date']} {show_time}", show_time_format)
    for show_time in data['time_list']
]

# generate all show objects using list comprehension and bulk create later
show_objects = [
    Show(event=event, date_time=first_day_timing + timedelta(days=day_cnt))
    for day_cnt in range(total_days)
    for first_day_timing in first_day_timings
]

Show.objects.bulk_create(show_objects)
```

Enhancements made on the existing code:

1. Reduced the number of instances date/time is getting parsed and hours/minutes are getting computed.
2. Use list comprehension to generate show objects and bulk create instead of creating one object at a time in a transaction.